# PHP MYSQL compare date time

Tags: mysql, datetime, select

I have a field in a table called created_at which i would to compare with two different dates.

e.g. created_at BETWEEN '2011-08-01 13:23:21' AND '2011-08-07 13:23:21'

i like to show all records which created in these two dates.

i have tried different method but still with no luck.

Comment: you want to show all records which are between date1 and date2?

Answer (score 4):

First be sure to set your date_field to DATETIME type, then do the query like this:

`SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE date_field >= '2011-08-01 13:23:21' AND date_field <= '2011-08-07 13:23:21'`

Answer (score 0):

```
SUBSTRING(now(), 1, 10) = '2015-0-15'
```

Comment: can you add some explanation?